# How can I get custom Text View's inputView?

Tags: ios, uitextview, inputview

I use EGOTextView to show some Attributed string like emotion (not emoji), because system's UITextView or UITextField can not show image with text.

But I cannot get the inputView with EGOTextView, How can I get it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inputView` property is defined as read-only in `UIResponder`, which is a superclass of `EGOTextView`.  So you just need a way to make your instance of `EGOTextView` return something non-nil from `inputView`.

Make a subclass of `EGOTextView` that declares and implements a `readwrite` version of the `inputView` property, and use your subclass.

Comment: I think the inputView should be keyboard view, but how I can get the instance of keyboard?

Comment: You can't get an instance of the keyboard.  You can use `inputView` to display something *instead of* the keyboard.  If you just want the keyboard, then `inputView` should return nil (which is the default).

Comment: Yes, the inputView is nil when the keyboard is shown. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you had checked the implementation of `EGOTextView` you had find that this class is not a subclass of `UITextView1 or`UITextField`so it doesn't have`inputView`.

Comment: [`UIResponder` declares `inputView`.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-SW22)  It just doesn't provide a setter for changing it.  Any subclass of `UIResponder` (which means any view) can override `inputView` to return something non-nil.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't subclass of UITextView or UITextField, but when the EGOTextView becomeFirstResponder really has a keyboard pop up, can I get the view to set into inputView?